# dictionary: {if true then <key-value exist>} only want key-value pair to exist under certain condition with single line expression (Python)

Tags: python

I changed the code thanks for correction

I'm quite new to python and find the single line if-else condition `<expression 1> if <condition> else <expression 2>` quite handy and wonder if I could directly implement it into a dictionary to make a more flexible dictionary: if certain statement is valid then a key-value pair would exist, else it wouldn't exist in the dictionary

here's a super simplified example code, might not make much sense but i hope could clarif what i mean:

```
animals = ['dog', 'duck', 'goose', 'swan']
legs = [4, 2, 2, 2]
beak_color = ['black','red', 'yellow']

for i in range(len(animals)):
    features = {'legs_num': legs[i], [None if animals[i] == 'dogs' else 'beak': beak_color[i - 1]]}
    print(features)
```

but there would be a red underline for 'None if animals[i] == 'dogs' else 'beak':' saying

***Dictionary entries must contain key/value pairs***

The error might raised because python don't recognize `None` as Key-Value element.

Is it possible to fix the problem? Otherwise I'll just simply add new key value pair without this single line expression

Comment: First of all, dictionaries have unique keys, so even if you were able to create a dict, it will have only one key:value pair because there is only one key ('legs_num'). But it's still not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I understand you may be asking the question just to learn about the language and see what can be done, but doing this will likely make your code very unreadable. you may be able to perform something in a single line of code, but that doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this in a single line is to use the `|` operator which [merges dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) (requires Python 3.9 or later).

Here, the code merges `{'legs_num': legs[i]}` with a dict which is conditionally either `{}`, or `beak_color[i-1]`.

```
animals = ['dog', 'duck', 'goose', 'swan']
legs = [4, 2, 5, 6]
beak_color = ['black', 'red', 'yellow']

for i in range(len(animals)):
    features = {'legs_num': legs[i]} | ({} if animals[i] == 'dog' else {'beak': beak_color[i-1]})
    print(features)
```

Output:

```
{'legs_num': 4}
{'legs_num': 2, 'beak': 'black'}
{'legs_num': 5, 'beak': 'red'}
{'legs_num': 6, 'beak': 'yellow'}
```

Like @DeanVanGreunen's answer, I changed your original code so that `legs` has 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to make a few new lines of code

```py
animals = ['dog', 'duck', 'goose', 'swan']
legs = [4, 2, 5, 6]
# Animal and legs should have the same array size
beak_color = ['black','red', 'yellow']

for i in range(len(animals)):
    features = {'legs_num': legs[i]}
    if animals[i] != 'dog':
        features['beak'] = beak_color[i - 1]
    print(features)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction of the list length :) but this will still print out 'beak': None. I'm sorry for the confusion but what I meant that the 'beak' would not exist at all, is it possible then?

Comment: @FliegendeButter try my code